# Create a custom backend listener for jmeter for sending test variables and other data to Influxdb

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have a requirement to send custom parameters, variables and properties to InfluxDB as a part of my Jmeter tests so that we can analyze test data based on the functionality of the application.
As of now I can use backend listener for influxdb but it only has limited fields which would not be helpful in my case since I want to send more relevant data based on the application functionality.
Can someone point/help with right resources to develop a custom backend listener to send custom data to InfluxDB from jmeter and not depend on the existing listener.
I want a flexible option to send data as per our application and not restrict to only fields in listener.

Currently I am using a View Results in table to save this custom data to CSV files. The sample is shown in below snapshot.
[image]

To do this I have modified our user.properties files and specify the sample_variables, like below:
sample_variables=employee_code,user_id,transName,transType,transVer,deptID,deptType,deptName

But instead of using an additional listener, I would like to send these variables for EACH HIT (for every sample) to the influxDB. How do I achieve it? Any further help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option is just using normal [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to send the metrics you want via [InfluxDB API](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/api/).

---

If you still want to implement a custom listener you can first of all take a look at the existing [Backend Listener code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.4.1/src/components/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend)

Then get familiarized with the following materials:

- [How to write a plugin for JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html)
- [How to write your own JMeter listener. A guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-write-your-own-jmeter-listener-guide)

and maybe see a reference project like [jmeter-backend-azure](https://github.com/adrianmo/jmeter-backend-azure)